# How do I bubble up an Exception to my UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, try-catch

I have an aspx page that, on a button click, creates an instance of a serviceRefernece object. In the code behind for my page I have the call wrapped in a try/catch.

```
        try
        {
            var client = GetClient();
            var request = new ActiveVerificationRequestDC();
            var response = client.GetActiveVerification(request);
            DoSomethingWithTheResponse(response);      

        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            LogError(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            throw;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var args = new[] { MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message };
            DisplayError(args);
        }
```

The svc file that is referenced is using pretty much the same pattern. It is calling an internal client over net.tcp. The call is wrapped in a try/catch

```
        try
        {
            var client = new InternalServiceClient();
            var response = client.GetActiveVerification(request);
            client.Close();
            return response;

        }
        catch (FaultException fe)
        {
            LogError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, fe);
            throw; 
        }
```

Here is my problem, how do I get errors here to bubble up to my UI catch statement? When I leave it like this, I get an unhandled exception error from visual studio. I have tried removing the `throw` which makes me specify a return value, and I return null. This makes the UI not work correctly. I have tried `throw new Exception(fe.message)` and I get the same problem with the unhandled exception. Basically my question is how can I accomplish what I need? What am I missing?

Comment: The unhandled exception sounds like it occurs on a service boundary, hence why Visual Studio will catch it. Will Visual Studio not let you continue execution? I presume your page `catch (Exception ex)` or `catch (FaultException ex)` catch handler never executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate try/catch block around your try/catch block. You have it such that you will catch a FaultException and any type of Exception, but your Exception block will not catch your throw from FaultException. So, just enclose this with another try/catch or handle it within both the FaultException catch and the Exception catch.

Comment: Or you could remove the `catch (FaultException ex)`
 handler on the ASPX page, depending on the logging criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be the throwing of another exception in your second code snippet that isn't of the type `FaultException`; such an exception would pass as unhandled in this situation. Maybe you should add another `catch` block to your second code snippet that catches exceptions of the type `Exception`:

```
    catch (FaultException fe)
    {
        LogError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, fe);
        throw; 
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `FaultException` you are re-throwing a generic type? Are the relevant classes detailed by any `FaultContract` attributes accessible to all assemblies in this execution stack?

**Edit:** In your first code snippet ...

```
   catch (FaultException ex)
    {
        LogError(ex, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        throw;
    }
```

If the unhandled error occurs on the `throw` statement of this handler, then @MCain is right.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you have to throw in the catch block for the error to bubble up

```
try
{
}
catch (SqlException _SqlException)
{
  //Log Error to file
  throw;
}
catch (IOException _IOexception)
{
  //Log Error to file
  throw;
}
catch (Exception _exception)
{
  //Log Error to file
  throw;
}
```

This kind of a block will be in the calling method